# Image Being Saved is Not Appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, uiimageview

I am trying to save my photo using Core Data, however, when I take the photo and return to the `DetailViewController`nothing is seen in the `UIImageView`. Let me explain exactly what happens:
The user pushes the "Add A Profile Picture" button which prompts them to take a photo after the photo is taken as normal it shows the preview of the photo where the user can either retake the photo or save the image. When they push save image the ViewController is dismissed and no photo is seen in the `UIImageView` when I push save and go back into this view controller nothing is still seen in the `UIImageView`.

I have included my code below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.                                                                                                                                                                                   

if (self.device) {
    [self.scoutNameText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [self.scoutContactText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"number"]];
    [self.scoutTeamText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"team"]];
    [self.email setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"email"]];
    [self.pick1 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick1"]];
    [self.pick2 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick2"]];
    [self.pick3 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick3"]];
    [self.pick4 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick4"]];
    [self.pick5 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick5"]];
    [self.pick6 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick6"]];
    [self.jobtitle setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"jobtitle"]];



}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scout.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[self.photo setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

}

- (IBAction)ProfilePhoto:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scout.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[self.photo setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];


[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

// Update existing device
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutNameText.text forKey:@"name"];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutContactText.text forKey:@"number"];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutTeamText.text forKey:@"team"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick1.text forKey:@"pick1"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick2.text forKey:@"pick2"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick3.text forKey:@"pick3"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick4.text forKey:@"pick4"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick5.text forKey:@"pick5"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick6.text forKey:@"pick6"];
[self.device setValue:self.email.text forKey:@"email"];
[self.device setValue:self.jobtitle.text forKey:@"jobtitle"];




 NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question and help me! Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting `imageData`? Check once `imageData.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (try to) save the image in the `NSDocumentationDirectory` ("Documentation"),
 which does not exist by default, so that

```
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

fails and

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

returns `nil`. You probably want to save the image in the `NSDocumentDirectory`
("Documents") instead.

Generally, I would recommend to always check the return value of calls like

```
BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

to detect errors like this.

Apart from that, I cannot see in your code that the image (or image path) is stored
in the managed object `self.device` anywhere, which means that it is not stored 
in Core Data at all.

Comment: I changed the `NSDocumentationDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory` however nothing is still returned.

Comment: @TimothyRoeJr.: Did you check the return value of `[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]` ? Did you check (in the file system) if a file has actually been written to the Documents directory? What does `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]` return ?

Comment: Nothing is still returned.

Comment: @TimothyRoeJr.: I am trying to help, but it is difficult if you don't provide all information. I asked 3 different questions in my last comment. Can you answer all three of them? This might be useful to locate the problem.

Comment: I apologize I've been had this problem for 3 months, I'm just a little frustrated. I apologize, So I checked the return value of the [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES] an I get nothing returned in console. According to the console I used a NSLog(filePath) to find exactly where the file is being saved. I am unable to locate that exact directory. [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] returns nothing in the console. If I am missing anything feel free to let me know.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all your help!